# How to pass fontAwesome icon to CSS content via data attribute

Tags: html, css, angularjs, font-awesome

I'm using a mixture of angular, html and css for my frontend build and I'm trying to change a font awesome icon onclick with angular. However, I can't get it to pass the unicode to css and display the correct icon. It just prints out the unicode instead.

Here is my CSS:

```
&:before {
        content: attr(data-icon);
        font-family: "fontAwesome";
        font-size: 2em;
        position: absolute;
        left: .65em;
        top: .25em;
    }
```

My html/angular:

```
<div class="accordion--title" ng-click="showAccordionDetail = !showAccordionDetail" ng-attr-data-icon="{{showAccordionDetail && '\f107' || '\f106' }}">
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `<i>` tag for your icon (as suggested in the Fontawesome [examples](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)) and then use the `ng-class` directive? Or is using the data attribute a hard requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-class`, much easier to do this:

```
<div
    ng-init="showAccordionDetail = false"
    class="accordion--title"
    ng-click="showAccordionDetail = !showAccordionDetail" 
    ng-class="{true:'fa fa-angle-down', false: 'fa fa-angle-right'}[showAccordionDetail]">
        click me
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I didn't think of this option :)

Answer (score 0):

As Enkode's answer, it's easier to use `ng-class` but I've made some changes to make it simpler.

```
<div ng-init="showAccordionDetail = false"
     class="accordion--title"
     ng-click="showAccordionDetail = !showAccordionDetail" 
     ng-class="{'fa fa-angle-down': showAccordionDetail, 'fa fa-angle-right': !showAccordionDetail}">
    click me
</div>
```

Hope this helps.